# Google Chrome Resources Directory

Tags: google-chrome, python, google-chrome-extensions, javascript, html5

about a year ago I remember making a google-styled application with JavaScript/HTML (very basic). I went back to making a similar app but started from scratch using JavaScript/HTML5/CSS3 and Python 2.7, and as a preloader I found that you can use the `chrome://resources/images/throbber.svg` file directory straight from Google Chrome.

I was wondering where this root directory is located? I am using Windows 7 Professional, Chrome version 26 and Chrome Canary version 27. I tried looking through `C:/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/application/VisualElements` with no avail, all that is is Windows 8 Metro elements. I also tried just typing in the omnibox `chrome://resources/` but it pulls an **Error 2 (net::ERR_FAILED): Unknown error** 404-ish page.

I am assuming it has other UI elements, not just the throbber, so that's why I am wondering how to get to the directory so I can browse the other files.

- Where is the file directory and how can I get to it?
- Is the file directory protected and/or hidden so I can't get to it?
- If the above statement is true, is there a list of GUI elements that I can type
  manually similar to `throbber.svg`?

**Edit:**

I'll go ahead and compile (start) a list of what I already know, and anyone who can answer might finish the list?

- `chrome://resources/images/throbber.svg`
- `chrome://resources/images/trash.png`
- `chrome://resources/css/chrome_shared.css`
- `chrome://resources/css/widgets.css`
- `chrome://resources/css/list.css`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's an embedded resource, not a file you can directly access in a folder. A query like this is easily answered - just look through the [Chromium source code](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/refs/heads/master/ui/webui/resources).

Here's what's present under `src/ui/webui/resources`:

- [css](http://code.google.com/searchframe#OAMlx_jo-ck/src/ui/webui/resources/css/)
- [html](http://code.google.com/searchframe#OAMlx_jo-ck/src/ui/webui/resources/html/)
- [images](http://code.google.com/searchframe#OAMlx_jo-ck/src/ui/webui/resources/images/)
- [js](http://code.google.com/searchframe#OAMlx_jo-ck/src/ui/webui/resources/js/)